# Why is Flutter Navigator not working after adding calculation to onTap?

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter navigator is not working after I added the bold code below to it. Does anybody know why? When I want to push to the ResultsPage, it does not work after adding the calculation to it.

```
calculate_button(
            onTap: () {
              **CalculationBrain calculator = CalculationBrain();
              String bmi = calculator.getBMI(weight, height);**
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultsPage(bmi)),
              );
            },
```

```
class ResultsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  **ResultsPage (this.bmi);
  String bmi;**
``
```

```
 String getBMI (weight, height) {
   String bmi = weight/pow(height/100, 2).toStringAsFixed(1);
   return bmi;
  }
```

``

Comment: Welcome, do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Hi, yes I am getting the following error message: 

======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' of 'other'

Comment: Can you show us the getBMI function? It looks like getBMI returns a num which you try to save in a string

Comment: I just added the getBMI function to my post above :)

Comment: Checkout my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your parameters a double type and put parentheses around your calculation, this should work

```
String getBMI(double weight, double height) {
    String bmi = (weight / pow(height / 100, 2)).toStringAsFixed(1);
    return bmi;
  }
```